# jquery datepicker work in dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I follow this instruction: http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/07/01/a-simple-tutorial-on-asp-net-dynamic-data.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage
I have added the links to my ASP.NET Dynamic Data master page as follow:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="NewStyles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I add this code on the top of my DateTime_Edit.ascx.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').datepicker();
});
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Site.master file that the `EnablePartialRendering` value is `false` and not `true`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Page.ResolveURL() in src attribiute. Like this one:

```
<script src='<%=Page.ResolveURL("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```